# TFS2010: Set up an alert that will email a member in the team when a work item is assigned to them

Tags: tfs, alerts

I want to notify each team member when a work item is assigned to them. I know how to set up an alert per team member (so if there are 10 team members I set up 10 seperate alerts) but **is there a way to set up a single alert that will email the person the work item is assigned to?**

I have the filter complete:

```
"PortfolioProject" = 'MyProject' AND ("CoreFields/StringFields/Field[ReferenceName='System.AssignedTo']/OldValue" <> '@Me' AND "CoreFields/StringFields/Field[ReferenceName='System.AssignedTo']/NewValue" = '@Me')
```

.. but I am stuck on **how to make the email address that the alert is sent to generic**. Putting @Me in the "Send To:" field unsurprisingly does not work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [TFS Global Alerts](https://tfsalerts.codeplex.com/) which is specifically designed for this kind of thing.

Comment: Look like just the ticket. Thanks, Lars.

Comment: I just looked at this and it seems like it is for sending alerts to GROUPS of users. Is there a way to say: when a TFS item changes and is assigned to that person, email THAT person?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [TFS Event Handler](http://tfseventhandler.codeplex.com/)

It appears it is in the process of being upgraded too:

[TFS Event Handler for Team Foundation Server 2010](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/tfs-event-handler-for-team-foundation-server-2010/)