# TFS 2010 Email Alerts

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I found this post, which seems to be an exact duplicate, but I can't figure out how to get the answer to work for me so I'm posting again...

[TFS2010: Set up an alert that will email a member in the team when a work item is assigned to them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609976/tfs2010-set-up-an-alert-that-will-email-a-member-in-the-team-when-a-work-item-is/6625784#comment-8188496)

I want anyone (not everyone) using TFS to receive an email when they are assigned an item or when an item assigned to them changes. So, when the alert happens, the person who is currently assigned the item will receive an email.

I know I can set up this on a per-person basis with Alerts Explorer, but I can't figure out how to do this for everyone at once.

I looked at https://tfsalerts.codeplex.com/, but it looks like it's used to send alerts to groups of people...I only want to send the alert to a single relevant person (the equivalent of @Me). If this tool can do that, I'm not sure how to make it do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you want to do is write a TFS Server Plugin. This plugin will fire whenever a certain event occurs. In your case, you will want to catch the WorkItemChangedEvent. In the notification, you will find old and new values of each field. By checking whether the **assigned to** field changed, you will know whether the WI has been reassigned.

Once you determined that the WI has been reassigned, you can take the *New Value*, and go to Active Directory (assuming you're using it), and get the email address. Finally, send a message.

For a code example of writing a robust server plugin (that happens to target the WorkItemChangedEvent, check out this blog post: [How to Write a Robust TFS Server Plugin](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/assafstone/archive/2011/07/29/how-to-write-a-robust-tfs-server-plugin-with-job-extensions.aspx)

Comment: ...I really need to write a plugin for something so simple?

Comment: Yep.  I'm glad that TFS doesn't support spamming users out of the box.  People can opt into it individually and if you really need to push out alerts it's easy enough to add.

Comment: Writing the plugin is about an hour's work. It *is* a simple solution for a simple problem.

Comment: Fair enough...but it should be 1 minute's work, not 1 hour's work.