# TFS2010 Alerts Explorer hardcode the Email Adreeses

Tags: tfs, tfs-alerts

TFS alert explorer is hard coded the email addressees is there is a say from where we cannot hardcode the email address? and it directly send the email. problem with following scenario.

if team project is "test-Project" work item type is "bug" and assign to is "any person" then it will send the email to "any person" automatically.

means whatever the assign to is . it will have to send the mail to that person which is assigned.

problem is the manually typing the email address in alert explorer.

there is a way to automatically send the email which is

sorry for my bad English . sorry if i cannot defined my problem as my English is to week.

Comment: possible duplicate of [TFS 2010 Email Alerts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886834/tfs-2010-email-alerts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Tfs 2010 you need to use a server plugin to achieve this, you can [write you own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886834/tfs-2010-email-alerts) or use one of the many freely available ones already out there.

[Team Alerts](http://fszlin.dymetis.com/post/2011/03/22/Event-Notification-Plugin-for-TFS-2010.aspx)

[Tfs Global Alerts](https://tfsalerts.codeplex.com/)

In Tfs 2012 you can use group alerts which are one of the new features.

Comment: i have checked the both , but tfs global alerts does not meet my requirements , plus team alert is not working . i dont know what is the problem but team alert is not working . other wise team alert is very awsom. and it v usefull. i want that , but it is not working. any other solution??

Comment: Can you define "not working" a bit better? maybe we can help set it up correctly.

Comment: yes betty, when im putting the dll, and config file as codeplex says.but it does not do any action

Comment: sorrry my english....... but i read the whole artical of team alert.after putting config file and dll in application tier...>plugins.the tfs is not restarting . as artical said tfs will restart after putting the files. and even not a single change is happen.i have tested the correct config file as in codeplex issue traker field.there are lot of people sharing their problem.

Comment: @betty.......as now i wrote a plugin. which send only the notification when something is assign to person. the person will recieve a mail that he is assigned to this work item...... now what im trying to do is , i want a simple guide from which i can write a code of change fields in any work item. i want a email as same as the alert explorer is sending. so how could i send the same email as alert explorer is sending.

Comment: TFS builds its emails using xml templates, Team Alert uses the same templates. Check how it does it http://teamalert.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/79962#1423121

Comment: bro i found that, it is using SmtpClient for sending mail msg.but also it have some eventDocuments.how can i use this in my server plugin?